# Remove event listeners for specific sub-elements if I have added listener to a parent element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here in my program I have added an onclick listener to the table. What I want is that when the listener fires [when I click on a table cell], I want to disable the listener for that particular cell. Is there a possible way to do that other than adding listener to each td elements and removing the listener of the particular td when it fires.?
My html looks like this :

```
                    <table id="board">
                        <tr>
                            <td id="c1"> 1</td>
                            <td id="c2"> 2</td>
                            <td id="c3"> 3</td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr>
                            <td id="c4"> 4</td>
                            <td id="c5"> 5</td>
                            <td id="c6"> 6</td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr>
                            <td id="c7"> 7</td>
                            <td id="c8"> 8</td>
                            <td id="c9"> 9</td>
                        </tr>   
                    </table>
```

and the listener I added is like this :

```
var table = getId("board", 1);
table.addEventListener('click', sample , false);
function sample( evt ) {
   alert(evt.target.innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: when you click, add some dummy class for that td cell. Next time check with that class. If it is available then it is already clicked otherwise new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an event handler direcly on the clicked element that stops the event from propagating

```
function sample(evt) {
    alert(evt.target.innerHTML)
    evt.target.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qnYWt/)

Answer (score 2):

You can store some flag on those elements already clicked. For example in data attribute:

```
function sample(evt) {
    var target = evt.target;

    if (!target.getAttribute('data-clicked')) {
        target.setAttribute('data-clicked', true);
        alert(evt.target.innerHTML);
    }
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7SMrE/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'one' function which adds the listener once.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kk4T8/1/)

HTML code:

```
<table id="board">
                    <tr>
                        <td id="c1" class="test"> 1</td>
                        <td id="c2" class="test"> 2</td>
                        <td id="c3" class="test"> 3</td>
                    </tr>   
                    <tr>
                        <td id="c4" class="test"> 4</td>
                        <td id="c5" class="test"> 5</td>
                        <td id="c6" class="test"> 6</td>
                    </tr>   
                    <tr>
                        <td id="c7" class="test"> 7</td>
                        <td id="c8" class="test"> 8</td>
                        <td id="c9" class="test"> 9</td>
                    </tr>   
                </table>
```

JS:

```
$('.test').one('click', function(){
  alert('hi');
})
```

like this you have the listener on each cell until you click the particular cell